# Local Visual Studio connected to Azure SQL DB - slow connection

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm looking for some advice. I have been developing web apps over the past few years using Visual Studio on an Azure VM connected to an Azure SQL Database.

I recently decided to move Visual Studio to a new local PC to improve VM connection latency and to reduce the costs of using an Azure VM.

Coding is great (in my new config) because everything is local and therefore quicker but debugging and testing is very slow; I guess this is because of the data pulls from the Azure SQL Database across the internet.

I've researched alternative configs:

A - Create a local db sync with my Azure db - connecting my web-app to a local SQL db that syncs with the Azure DB may improve matters because I guess the data is local. I'm not sure if there are any constraints/delays as the database syncs.

B - Create a local copy of my Azure db - whilst this option would resolve my latency option, I often need to debug live data and therefore waiting for a copy to download will possibly create its own inefficiencies.

Before I go ahead and trial any of these solutions, I'd like to know what a conventional setup might look like and any other suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**Update 7 March**
Neither solution has provided me with a satisfactory outcome:

A - I could not achieve a sync to my local PC. I don't believe that this function is currently supported.

B - creating a copy of my Azure db to my localDb created many issues with my project's Entity Framework, which had to be altered - which in turn is not practical when I want to point my development back to Azure SQL database.

I suppose options available still are:

C - create a Azure webapp (for development), post each change up to there to test/debug - this seems like a cumbersome arrangement.

D - stick with the VM - (unnecessarily expensive)!

I'm still keen to hear from other users that have a local pc development linked to Azure SQL databases. How do you get around the slow response (from data download).

Apologies if I am completely missing the point here, or if my setup is completely unconventional.

Comment: If you go with option A, what would be the method are going to use to sync Azure DB with your local DB? Have you thought of anything?

Comment: What is the reason for having same database that are synced in two places?
Except if you are doing development in the production environment...

Comment: Chathuranga - I was going to use the db sync option within Azure.

Comment: Dusan - it tends to be debugging real-time problems - there is probably a better way to do this?

Comment: @Steven Actually, you are using the Azure SQL managed instance,  data sync doesn't support managed instance for now. So option A doesn't work.